# call an overloaded operator w/o loading the package in R

Tags: r

in R, I can do `package::fun()`, how to make the call if the `fun()` is an overloaded operator, e.g. `+`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following workaround:

```
dplyr::`%>%`(c(1,3,7), list())
```

Yo will specify left-hand and right-hand side parameters of the operator in parentheses.

The result will be the same as if you called:

```
library(dplyr) 
c(1,3,7) %>% list()
```

So for your case it will be spelled as

```
packagename::`+`(LHS, RHS)
```

Comment: How is this different (enough) from my answer submitted over 15 hours before this?

Comment: Really sorry, @r2evans. I frankly didn`t notice it on my smartphone's small screen as I was on the way when I was answering. The best I could invent was to upvote your answer for compensation. Should I delete my answer?

Comment: No need, thanks. I'm not looking for compensation, it's a double outside-the-norm: a redundant answer, and the asker accepted the latter of the two.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but not in its infix mode.

Demonstration in an R session without `data.table` loaded:

```r
data.table::`%like%`("Mary", "^Mar")
# [1] TRUE
"Mary" %like% "^Mar"
# Error in "Mary" %like% "^Mar" : could not find function "%like%"
"Mary" data.table::`%like%` "^Mar"
# Error: unexpected symbol in ""Mary" data.table"

library(data.table)
"Mary" %like% "^Mar"
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: @blueskyddd  I guess you need to accept this answer as it was answered before mine. r2evans I cannot delete my answer. I get a message "you cannot delete this accepted answer"

Comment: _Please_, no need @asd-tm.

Comment: SO throws an error when I try to delete my answer. Sorry anyway.

Comment: So long as it is accepted and it does not have a negative vote count, it cannot be deleted. _You're fine_, thank you for the intended results.

Answer (score 2):

You need to load the package (which happens implicitly when accessing names from a package via `::`), but you don’t need to attach it. However, if you want to use operators using the usual operator syntax, you need to at least import the relevant name. You can do this manually with assignment, e.g.:

```
`%op%` = pkg::`%op%`
```

Note that this is only necessary if the operator isn’t an S3 method with a generic defined in another, attached package. In that case, merely loading the package is sufficient; this is the situation shown in G. Grothendieck’s solution: `+` is a generic defined in the ‘base’ package, and ‘ggplot2’ defines a method `+.gg`.

For non-S3 operators, an alternative solution to the manual assignment is to import the operator using the [package ‘box’](https://klmr.me/box/):

```
box::use(
  pkg[`%op%`],
)
```

Note that ‘box’ is a *holistic* solution: for best results, it should be used *exclusively* (i.e. not alongside other package loading mechanisms such as `library()`).

---

`library()` also has an argument `include.only`, which theoretically allows you to attach only parts of the package; for instance, you’d write `library(pkg, include.only = '+')`. However, this is fundamentally broken: subsequent attempts to attach some or all names from the same package via `library()` will fail silently. I therefore recommend against using this approach.

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean without *attaching* the package. The package must be *loaded* to use it. Using `::` or `:::` will load the package and once the package is loaded simply using `+` will find the method. In this case it finds `+.gg` in ggplot2. `sessionInfo()` will show which packages are attached and which are loaded but not attached.  Try this on a fresh instance of R.

```
ggplot2::ggplot(BOD, ggplot2::aes(Time, demand)) +
  ggplot2::geom_point()

sessionInfo()
```

Comment: Yes, `attach` is the correct term. Thanks!